# Pyinstaller: Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt4plugins

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, pyinstaller

When I run my .exe which is created by pyinstaller, it has the error message which is shown in the below screenshot.

[image: the error I got when I run the exe]

I use Python 3.6.4, pyinstaller 3.4 and PyQt5 5.12 to make my GUI program in Windows 10. Why does the .exe need the PySide module and PyQt4 when I run the .exe? I don't understand it. The .py can run without any bugs.

Actually, before I got this error I had the error `Exception:Cannot find PyQt4 plugin directories` during the process the exe is being produced, but I thought I didn't need PyQt4 so I uninstalled it. Then the pyinstaller process continued until I got a new error.

```
Exception:
Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
Paths checked: C:/qt64/qt_1544645195969/_h_env/Library/plugins
```

I solved it by copying the pyqt5qmlplugin.dll to the path mentioned above `C:/qt64/qt_1544645195969/_h_env/Library/plugins`. Finally I got the .exe, but unfortunately I still got an error which is shown in the screenshot, and I can't install PyQt4 with pip. It reports:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )  
No matching distribution found for PyQt4
```

I also can't install PySide because `only these Python versions are supported: [(2.6), (2.7), (3.2), (3.3), (3.4)]`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is creating a new environment with Python 3.5 and installing all the libraries required for the script in it. 
If you're using Anaconda, follow the steps below:

> conda create yourenvironmentname python=3.5
>
> conda activate yourenvironmentname

Replace "yourenvironmentname" with any name you would like for your environment.

If not using Anaconda:

> pipenv --python 3.5

In case it does not work, try it with python 3.4 instead.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for me. And I do not think the error is caused by the python version.

Comment: i can transfer some .py program successfully with pyinstaller in same way. But the program mentioned in the screenshot always failed. during the running with command pyinstaller, there are always some module missing. Is it the reason?

Comment: Make sure you install all modules you import to the code in the environment you created, otherwise it will not run properly. If only the Python versions mentioned are supported, try running Pyinstaller from an environment with Python 3.4 installed instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that the installer is recognizing pyqt4. To fix this do the following:

1. Go to
   "\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py".
2. Comment out everything.
3. After this is done, rerun pyinstaller

   and it should work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyQt5 in your program go on "`pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py`" file in the following directory : `Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks.`

Replace

1. `PySide.QtCore` by `PySide2.QtCore` and
2. `PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication` by `PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication`

I tried to follow the upper steps by commenting the file and but did not work until I did this.

Comment: Just for future reference.  The rthooks folder is now placed under hooks, not loader, for PyInstaller 4.0